how to resolve the aws ecs container healthcheck fail?
1.ecs container helathcheck(shell)
enter image description here
2.postman call
enter image description here
3.unhealthy
enter image description here
postman call success.but ecs healthcheck fail,i don't know how to solve this problem,i feel very strange

Then your application must be "unhealthy". Have you checked your container logs / task logs? Is the healthCheck endpoint working? Try to remove the healthCheck and see if the task will start, then connect to it and try to curl from inside the container.

Does this application run as an ECS service with a load balancer?
